# Is there any way to extract attribute values for CSS selection?

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

What I'm thinking is along the lines of the `content` property's `attr()` value.

An example of the type of code I'm thinking of would be:

```
.class[attribute=attr(attribute)]:first-of-type .child{
    color: green;
}
```

I know this can be done in jQuery, but as I am unable to manipulate the page I'm restyling, it  would be best to have a CSS approach to this.

Edit: As this may be confusing for what I want, I'll supply some sample HTML for what I want selected.

```
<div class="class" attribute="mrmcpowned">
    <span class="child">Test1</span>
</div>
<div class="class" attribute="mrmcpowned">
    <span class="child">Test2</span>
</div>
<div class="class" attribute="mrmcpowned">
    <span class="child">Test3</span>
</div>
<div class="class" attribute="mrmcpowned">
    <span class="child">Test4</span>
</div>
<div class="class" attribute="friend">
    <span class="child">Test1</span>
</div>
<div class="class" attribute="friend">
    <span class="child">Test2</span>
</div>
<div class="class" attribute="friend">
    <span class="child">Test2</span>
</div>
<div class="class" attribute="friend">
    <span class="child">Test3</span>
</div>
<div class="class" attribute="otherfriend">
    <span class="child">Test1</span>
</div>
<div class="class" attribute="otherfriend">
    <span class="child">Test2</span>
</div>
<div class="class" attribute="otherfriend">
    <span class="child">Test3</span>
</div>
```

I'd like every first `<div>` with the attribute of whatever the value is to be selected without bias towards the value, e.g. first `<div>` with attributed value `mrmcpowned`, first `<div>` with attributed value `friend`, and first `<div>` with attributed value of `otherfriend`.

Comment: I believe currently it is not possible with CSS3.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#matching-attrs

Comment: What do you mean by extracting attribute values? What is `[attribute=attr(attribute)]` supposed to mean with regards to the `attr()` function?

Comment: In the CSS `content` property, `attr()` is used to display the content of the selected attribute for the selected CSS. For example, `attr(href)` of `<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Link</a>` would display http://stackoverflow.com. What i'm trying to select has repeated attributes in succession, and I'd only like the first of the list which has the repeated attributed value.

Comment: I prematurely submitted my comment, please refer back to it.

Comment: @mrmcpowned: I see, that makes more sense.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I believe you may be correct as well. What a shame :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short Answer is "No."

You cannot extract the attribute values as you desire in CSS. Your example may have a solution, however, depending on the exact parameters. That is...

### You Can Select the First Without *Bias*, but Not Without *Knowledge*

I am uncertain if this works for you or not, but it does follow literally what you asked for in your expanded edit to the question. You stated you wanted selection of the first "without bias towards the value." **This is 100% achievable, *assuming you have knowledge of all the possible values*.**

That is, the css can be constructed such that whatever value follows whatever differing value, a switch is made (this is without bias), but to get the css to do that, you need to know what all the possible individual values are. Based on your `.class[attribute=attr(attribute)]:first-of-type .child` pseudo code I have some doubts that this is the case, as that appears to be attempting to read *unknown* values. However, in case I have misread that, and you do in fact know all the possible values, but not the order they may appear in, then the following solution works:

[**See Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/S93fY/3/)

**CSS**

```
.class[attribute]:first-of-type .child,
.class[attribute="mrmcpowned"] + .class:not([attribute="mrmcpowned"]) .child,
.class[attribute="friend"] + .class:not([attribute="friend"]) .child,
.class[attribute="otherfriend"] + .class:not([attribute="otherfriend"]) .child {
    color: red;
}
```

Notice how the first selector simply selects the first type of item with any [attribute] defined, so it hits the very first of the group without bias to the attribute name. Then all the other selectors are positive/negative pairings using the adjacent sibling combinator. These pairings of *each particular attribute value* (which is why you need knowledge of all possible values) find the "breaks" when for example `friend` is `:not()` followed by another `friend`.

**If you do not have knowledge of all the possible values for the `attribute` then it is impossible with pure css.**

Comment: yeah, I've come to the conclusion that for now JS is the only way of achieving the end result I want since CSS has no knowledge functionality for selectors. Luckily for me, for what I wanted, I could simply copy the source and apply the JS. I'm giving you the points for having a thoroughly explained example, so anyone else looking into this understands.

Comment: I'd also like to add that the functionality I seek would be a nice addition to css, and I believe others would agree with me in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to put the attribute in brackets, almost like what you have there. Here is an example I pulled off of W3Schools for selecting input tags with the attribute "type" that equal "text"

```
input[type="text"]
{
width:150px;
display:block;
margin-bottom:10px;
background-color:yellow;
}
```

You can see the W3Schools link here for more info: [CSS Attribute Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Am I incorrect in thinking that you just want

```
.class[attribute="attr(attribute)"]:first-child .child{
    color: green; 
}
```

first of type is essentially the same as first child.

[here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JePrJ/)

Comment: You appear to have been confused by my initial question. I've expanded more with the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use the attribute selector.

HTML:

```
<img src="untitled.png" title="getme">
```

CSS:

```
[title="getme"] {
    display: block;
}
```

Here's the Mozilla reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: What I'm thinking is similar, but a step above that. Please refer to the edited question.